# capturing audio and video using flash in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, webcam, video-recording

I have a simple web application in asp.net in which i want to record interview of any candidate and after finish upload the video file to server.

I have searched a lot on internet but not found any satisfactory solution for this.

Any help will be highly appreciated .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I found some solutions in html5 using getUserMedia() but i need a solution in flash.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I completed my task as creating Solution through HTML5 Media Recorder API And Posted the recorded video to Asp.net Server by making a post request to aspx page from java script and saving that BLOB Stream to Server.

As it is only supported in chrome and Firefox now i am searching any flash solution that can run on Internet Explorer also.